# Javascript: Best way to send image in http post

Tags: javascript, http, post, canvas

I am building an app that streams video with the webcam from your device at a pretty high frame/picture per second.

I would like to know what is the best and most concise way of sending this stream of pictures one at a time with http post request. I have yet to find any seemingly over complicated methods.

```
context.drawImage(video,0,0, width, height);
image = context.getImageData(0,0,width,height);
```

This image object is in jpg format.

Comment: Wait your images are from a webcam, like from a getUserMedia call ? Then just send the raw video stream through webRTC.

Answer (score 0):

The TCP protocol alone is not fast enough to stream a video with a rate of 30fps.

You have many way to stream a media video:

- [Media Source Extension](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/)
- Find a API which use the Real Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP)
- Use the WebSockets over TCP protocol.